# the data could not be loaded completely because the maximum number of columns per sheet was exceeded

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, libreoffice

I am trying to redirect my python code into a csv file.
The problem is that I need 3072 columns and that's exactly what my code creates.

But when I open the created csv file only 1024 columns are displayed (which is the limit number of columns I think) and I got the following error "the data could not be loaded completely because the maximum number of columns per sheet was exceeded"

```
    import csv
    orig_stdout = sys.stdout
    f = open('image_to_pixel.csv', 'w')
    some code ....
    sys.stdout = orig_stdout
    f.close()
```

I am using Libreoffice 5.1.6.2, any idea to solve this problem guys ?
Thanks.

Comment: 1024 columns is (by now) the maximum number offered by LO. Maybe you can use rows (transpose the data)?

Comment: the problem is that I downloaded some csv files from internet that have more then 1024 columns and there were no errors.
4000 columns were displayed ! that's weird

Comment: See https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50916

Comment: @Geek: I doubt that you loaded a CSV with more than 1024 columns. I tested with LO 5.2.3.3, get a warning, and the data was truncated. Again: if you don't have more than 1024 *rows*  - can you transpose the file beofre loading into LO?

Answer (score 0):

You can import your csv file using dataframes. It will load all the 3072 columns.

```
import pandas as pd
read = pd.read_csv('image_to_pixel.csv',header=None)
your code.....
```